# Request a service registered as InstancePerRequest inside a service registered as SingleInstance

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, autofac

As stated in the title I am trying to resolve a service inside a method of a singleton, but so far I could not figure what the problem is.

```
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AssemblyUtils.GetAssemblies)
                .Where(t => t.IsClass && typeof(IProvider).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies)
                .SingleInstance();

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AssemblyUtils.GetAssemblies)
                .Where(t => t.IsClass && typeof(IService).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies)
                .InstancePerRequest();

public interface IApiStorageService : IService
{ }

public class SecurityProvider : ISecurityProvider
{
    public bool ValidateAccess(Guid sessionId, string routeTemplate, string method, out SessionData sessionData)
    {
        var apiStorageService = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetRequestLifetimeScope().Resolve<IApiStorageService>();
    }
}
```

The problem is that GetRequestLifetimeScope always returns null. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. What happens is that the Autofac web request tag is being created only then the execution reaches a controller.

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (securityProvider.ValidateAccess(sessionId, routeTemplate, request.Method.Method, out sessionData))
    {
        request.GetDependencyScope().GetRequestLifetimeScope().<IApiStorageService>()

    }
}
```

That code is executed in a Web API Handler before the request is passed over to the task responsable for invoking the Action.

```
        var apiStorageService = request.GetDependencyScope().GetRequestLifetimeScope().Resolve<IApiStorageService>();

        if (securityProvider.ValidateAccess(sessionId, routeTemplate, request.Method.Method, out sessionData, apiStorageService))
        {
        }
```

As a workaround I resolved the service before the method invocation and passed it as a parameter, it looks really nasty but I could not find a better way to do it.